# Angular Apollo grapqhql cache update

Tags: angular, rxjs, graphql, apollo

I stuck with my app flow after mutation is done.
I have a component with product details on which I can add product to the cart. If order is not yet started the product should be added and then the quantity should be updated. Then on my header the items quantity should be displayed.

//product.details.component

```
  addToProductCart(product) {
    this.spinnerService.showLoader();
    if (this.activeOrder === null
      || this.activeOrder === ''
      || this.activeOrder.lines.length === 0) { // order not yet created or line is empty
      this.addNewProduct()
        .pipe(
          switchMap((order) => {
            return this.adjustOrderLineGQL.mutate({ 
// here I am getting the error that orderLineId doesn't exist, but actually it is returned in order object
              orderLineId: order.data.addOfferToOrder.lines[0].id,
              quantity: this.productCounter
            })
          })
        )
        .subscribe((updatedOrder) => {
          this.spinnerService.hideLoader();
        })
    } else {
      if (this.activeOrder.lines.length > 0) { //cart is not empty
        const existingProduct = this.activeOrder.lines.filter((line) => {
          if (line.productVariant.sku === product.id) {
            return line
          }
        })
        if (existingProduct.length > 0) { // currently added product exists in active order, so only quantity is updated
          return this.adjustOrderLine(existingProduct[0].id, this.productCounter)
            .subscribe((result) => {
              this.spinnerService.hideLoader();
            });
        }
        else {
          this.addNewProduct()
            .pipe(
              switchMap((order) => {
                const currentProduct = order.data.addOfferToOrder.lines.filter((newLine) => {
                  if (newLine.productVariant.sku === product.id) {
                    return newLine;
                  }
                })
                return this.adjustOrderLine(currentProduct[0].id, this.productCounter)
              })
            )
            .subscribe((updatedOrder) => {
              this.spinnerService.hideLoader();
            })
        }
      } else {
        this.spinnerService.hideLoader();
      }
    }
  }

  addNewProduct() {
    return this.addOfferToOrderGQL.mutate({
      id: this.product.id,
      originalName: this.product.originalName,
      name: this.product.name,
      categoryId: this.product.category.id,
      price: this.product.price,
      deliveryCost: this.product.category.deliveryCost
    },
      {
        // refetchQueries: ()
        update: (cache, { data }) => { // here I assume I need to somehow refresh cache
          const cacheId = cache.identify(data.addOfferToOrder);
          cache.modify({
            fields: {
              addOfferToOrder: (existingFieldData, { toReference }) => {
                return [...existingFieldData, toReference(cacheId)]
              }
            }
          })
          console.log('OUTPUT: ProductsDetailsComponent -> addNewProduct -> cacheId', cacheId);
          console.log(data)
        }
      })
  }

// activeOrder

  getActiveOrder() {
    return this.getActiveOrderGQL.watch({ fetchPolicy: 'network-only' })
      .valueChanges
      .pipe(
      )
      .subscribe((result) => {
        this.activeOrder = result.data.activeOrder;
      })
  }
```

header.component.ts

```
  getActiveOrder(): any {
    console.log('in header');
    this.getActiveOrderGQL.watch( { fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network' })
      .valueChanges
      .pipe(
        pluck('data', 'activeOrder'),
        takeUntil(this.destroySubject),
        shareReplay()
      )
      .subscribe((order) => {
        console.log(order, 'header order');

        if (order) {
          this.orderService.refreshActiveOrder(order);
          this.selectedProductsCount = _.sumBy(order.lines, 'quantity');
        } else {
          this.selectedProductsCount = 0;
        }
      })
  }
```

If I refresh the page after adding the very first product then whole flow works and next products are added to cart and header is also immediately updated with correct product count.
Error says that after mutation the orderLineId doesn't exists, but order object returned by the mutation is correct an id has that property. So basically question is how to trigger mutation and then based on the returned value call another one query/mutation in the same and in the other components?

Comment: Could you post the full error message, please?

Comment: well, error says that after mutation the orderLineId doesn't exists, but order object returned by the mutation is correct an id has that property. So basically question is how to trigger mutation and then based on returned value call another one query/mutation in the same and in the other components?